# Removing Image from Table while Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, html-table

I am trying to scrape data from a table on wikipedia. While I have figured out how to scrape data from most of the columns on the table, there is one column I am having difficulty scraping because there is a "span" tag in the column as well as an "a" tag.

Specifically, if you refer to the table under the "Active Codes" section of this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217 you will see that the fifth column contains an image of a country flag (inside of a "span" tag) as well as the country name (inside of an "a" tag). Does anyone know how I could extract the text inside the "a" tag from the a tag of the fifth column of this table? So far I have written the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} #Needed to prevent 403 error on Wikipedia
req = urllib2.Request(wiki,headers=header)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

code = ""
num = ""
e = ""
currency = ""
country = ""

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll("td")
    #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
    if len(cells) == 5:
        code = cells[0].find(text=True)
        num = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
        #e = cells[2].find(text=True)
        currency = cells[3].find(text=True)
        country = cells[4].find(text=True)

        for x in range(len(num)):
            print(code + ", " + currency + ", " + country)
```

After I enter this code in the Terminal I return something like:

```
    AED, United Arab Emirates dirham,  
    AFN, Afghan afghani,  
    ALL, Albanian lek,
    ...
```

But I want to return something like:
        AED, United Arab Emirates dirham,  United Arab Emirates
        AFN, Afghan afghani, Afghanistan
        ALL, Albanian lek, Albania
        ...

Thanks for your help. If there is any way I can improve my question by making it more understandable, let me know. I am new to stack overflow. I have checked the forms to make sure a question like this hasn't already been answered, and unless I missed something I'm pretty sure it hasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    nodes = row.find_all('td')
    if nodes:
        print(nodes[0].text, nodes[3].text, nodes[4].text.strip())
```

output:

```
AED United Arab Emirates dirham United Arab Emirates
AFN Afghan afghani Afghanistan
ALL Albanian lek Albania
AMD Armenian dram Armenia
          ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that that column can contain multiple countries? So a text value might not be the best solution to store them. I'd rather prefer a list. You can simply `findAll` links (`a`) and obtain their text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(rsp.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "wikitable sortable" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
     cells = row.findAll("td")
     #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
     if len(cells) == 5:
         code = cells[0].find(text=True)
         num = cells[1].findAll(text=True)
         #e = cells[2].find(text=True)
         currency = cells[3].find(text=True)
         countries = [country.text for country in cells[4].findAll('a')]
```

Also you should note, that you can use the `requests` library which will facilitate the actual request to:

```
import requests

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217"
rsp = requests.get(wiki)
```

Also you only assign the values in the for loops to variables that are overwritten in the next loop. Think about something like:

```
codes = []
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    codes.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
```

And finally there is no need to instantiate variables in python like you did (`code = ""`)